# How does cURL upload a file?

Tags: php, file-upload, curl, imageshack

I am attempting to post an image to imageshack.us and have found a php curl script that works perfectly, except that the script is written to target a file on the file system. I already have the image data in a php variable, so having to write it to a file just to have curl read it in and do the post seems silly.

I'm just wondering if I can get curl to achieve the same end result, by passing it the image data myself?

Here's how it's currently doing it:

```
$post['fileupload'] = "@".$filename;
...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
...
```

Comment: You could pipe the image data to cURL, but I can't remember off the top of my head the proper command-line parameters (or PHP functions) to do it.

Comment: Is there any way I can read the final raw http request curl constructs? If I can just see what it's doing that might let me figure it out.

Comment: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php - `curl_getinfo()` can be used to get at least the header info (see CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT).  But to get the *entire* request, I think you'll have to go Ignacio's route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, here is how I managed to output a complete curl request to a file so I could see how it was constructing the raw request:

```
curl --trace-ascii curltrace.txt --header "Connection: close" --form "fileupload=@bug.png" --form "key=thisismykey" http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php
```

That ended up helping me out immensely, in case anyone else could benefit from it.